# restrict the NFTs of my contract (ERC721) to be traded on marketplaces?

Tags: contract-design, nft, erc-721, opensea, erc165

Are there tricks in solidity to prevent the NFTs minted by an ERC721 contract to be

(a) not recognizable and

(b) not being transferable

by marketplaces like OpenSea, SuperRare.

I see those possible solutions

1. Ban addresses of those marketplaces. If this is possible, which addresses should be blocked from using the contract, could you please provide examples or addresses?
2. disable the interface of ERC721 and ERC721Enumrable (described in ERC-165)? I think this could just prevent (a) but not (b). is this correct?

Comment: Whatever restriction techniques you come up with, I'll just come up with some other way to get around it

Comment: @WilliamEntriken yes I agree

Answer (score 0):

It's generally not recommended to try to prevent the recognition or transfer of NFTs by marketplaces like OpenSea or SuperRare. These platforms rely on standard interfaces and conventions, and if your NFTs don't conform to those standards, they may not be listed or recognized by these marketplaces. That being said if you want to prevent these marketplaces' recognition and transfer of your NFTs with proposed solutions. Let's discuss each one of them:

1. **Ban addresses of those marketplaces:** Add access control to prevent specific
   addresses from interacting with your contract. You could create a whitelist of
   addresses that are allowed to interact with your contract and block the
   addresses of these marketplaces. However, this approach may not be
   effective in the long term, as these marketplaces may use different
   addresses or find ways to bypass your access control.
2. **Disable the interfaces of ERC721 and ERC721Enumerable:** You can try
   to disable the ERC721 and ERC721Enumerable interfaces by overriding
   the functions defined in those interfaces and making them revert.
   This would prevent marketplaces from using those interfaces to
   recognize or transfer your NFTs. However, this approach is not
   recommended, as it would make your contract non-compliant with the
   ERC721 standard, which could cause issues with other NFT platforms
   and wallets.

Banning specific addresses is generally not recommended, as this goes against the principles of decentralization and censorship resistance that blockchain technology aims to uphold. Additionally, banning specific addresses may not be effective in the long run, as new addresses can always be created.

Instead, a better approach may be to use access control mechanisms within the smart contract code to restrict specific actions to only authorized users or accounts. For example, you could use the [OpenZeppelin AccessControl library](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/tree/master/contracts/access) to define roles and permissions for specific actions within your ERC721 contract.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, where could I find the addresses of those marketplaces?

Comment: by "Disable the interfaces of ERC721 and ERC721Enumerable" what I meant here is to deliver a "false" when the supportsInterface method of ERC165 asks if this contract is ERC721. not to change the function signature

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are making an "Access Control" for checking bad marketplaces keep in mind you can do "allow all-remove each unwanted" or you can "allow none-add good marketplaces".

---

2. @MajdTL you can find the address of the OpenSea marketplace in the metamask(wallet message) after you click the button "List for sale":

*Permission request
https://testnets.opensea.io may access and spend this asset
Approved asset:
All of your NFT Burger #1
Granted to:
Contract (**0x1E004978...3c71**)
Data
Function: SetApprovalForAll
Parameters: true*

---

3. As for creating the restriction for a specific address, you will have to **override** functions **approve()** and **setApprovalForAll()** in the ERC721.

   ```
    function approve(...) public virtual overirde{
       // require check if address is in your mapping;
       super.approve(...);
    }
   ```

also you will need a function for setting those addresses restrictions.

```
    mapping (address => bool) isAddressAllowed;
```

Use modifier onlyOwner by Openzepplin Ownable.sol. To limit access to setting the values in mapping.