How to restrict selling and buying nft, but can transfer to user?
I'm using seaport protocol in marketplace and make customized erc721.
I want some specific erc721 cannot be sold or bought in marketplace, but can transfer from user to other user.
when I ask chatGPT, it says to use setApprovalForAll. but I wonder if there is a better way to solve this problem. any ideas?

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/148008/restrict-the-nfts-of-my-contract-erc721-to-be-traded-on-marketplaces

If you know all the marketplace contracts' addresses which you wanna to block, you can set the blacklist addresses in nft contract and block them, otherwise you can only disable all the contract's approval (setApprovalForAll) because we cant distinguish between a marketplace and other contracts.

Override the default transferFrom function in your ERC721 contract.
Within this function, implement logic to check if the transfer is happening within the allowed addresses (users who can receive the NFT).
function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) public virtual override {

  require(_isApprovedOrOwner(from, tokenId), "ERC721: transfer from unauthorized address");

  // Add check for authorized recipient address
  require(isAuthorizedRecipient(to), "Transfer to unauthorized address");

  _beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
  _balances[from] -= 1;
  _balances[to] += 1;
  _owners[tokenId] = to;
  emit Transfer(from, to, tokenId);
}

The original transferFrom function typically transfers ownership of an ERC721 token from one address (from) to another (to). This will modify it to include a check for authorized recipients.
This was just a basic example, you can further enhance it based on your requirements
Additionally you also need to implement this
mapping(address => bool) public authorizedRecipients;

function setAuthorizedRecipient(address recipient, bool authorized) public onlyOwner {
  authorizedRecipients[recipient] = authorized;
}

function isAuthorizedRecipient(address to) public view returns (bool) {
  return authorizedRecipients[to];
}

This way you can set the recipient address beforehand

To restrict selling and buying of specific ERC721 tokens in your marketplace while enabling user-to-user transfers:

Customize your ERC721 contract with a transferFrom function.
Add a setTransferable function to enable the marketplace contract to set token transfer ability.
Ensure tokens are always transferable but cannot be sold or bought in the marketplace.
Integrate the modified ERC721 contract with the Seaport protocol for marketplace functionality.

Here's the complete solution code:
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract CustomERC721 is ERC721, Ownable {
    
    address marketplaceAddress;
    mapping(uint256 => bool) public isTransferable;

    constructor() ERC721("CustomERC721", "CE721") {}

    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) public override {
        require(_isApprovedOrOwner(_msgSender(), tokenId), "ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved");
        require(isTransferable[tokenId], "Token is not transferable");

        _transfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }

    function setMarketplaceAddress(address _marketplaceAddress) external onlyOwner {
        marketplaceAddress = _marketplaceAddress;
    }

    function setTransferable(uint256 tokenId) external {
        require(_msgSender() == marketplaceAddress, "Caller is not the marketplace");

        isTransferable[tokenId] = true;
    }
}

// Integration with Seaport protocol for marketplace functionality
contract SeaportIntegration {
    CustomERC721 public nftContract;

    constructor(address _nftContractAddress) {
        nftContract = CustomERC721(_nftContractAddress);
    }

    // Additional marketplace functionalities can be implemented here
}

